# Correct usage with participle clause

Tags: verbs, participle-clauses

> He died fighting for a cause, **allowing** generations of people to live free from oppression.

Here, *allowing* is a participle that introduces a participial adverbial clause.

> The key to my glossy hair is not drying it too much, **leaving** hair mask on.

Why doesn't *leaving* work the same way in the example?

You can say: *Leaving it shiny and clean*, but not: *leaving hair mask on*.

Comment: Who says you can't say _leaving hair mask on_?

Comment: The only thing strange about the second sentence is it's missing an article or  pronoun: *leaving* ***(the / my)*** *hair mask on*. Typically

Comment: Just doesn't sound right in speech, so I thought it might have been ungrammatical. It sounds a little abrupt.